# JavaCV sample(FacePreview) on android not working

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I did everything as told in http://code.google.com/p/javacv/ (JavaCV Homepage). 
No errors in my code. But when I try to launch the application on  the android emulator it says " Unfortunately, appname has stopped. I have no idea where to look at now. Any suggestion anyone?

These are found in the logcat text file.

```
10-07 03:41:15.878: E/dalvikvm(1138): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.googlecode.javacv.facepreview-2/libjniopencv_core.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZSt10unexpectedv" referenced by "libjniopencv_core.so"...
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:455)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacv.facepreview.FaceView.<init>(FacePreview.java:85)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacv.facepreview.FacePreview.onCreate(FacePreview.java:51)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     ... 16 more
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:455)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.<clinit>(opencv_objdetect.java:97)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     ... 19 more
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     ... 20 more
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:455)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     ... 23 more
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     ... 24 more
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZSt10unexpectedv" referenced by "libjniopencv_core.so"...
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:361)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136)
10-07 03:41:15.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     ... 27 more
```

All answers are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the logcat here.

Comment: I have added them into the question. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: this is the console not logcat. provide your logcat after execution.

Comment: if you dont know how to open logcat then inside eclipse open window (left of help tab) then show view and then click others. there you find the logcat and click on it to show.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert this inside the build.gradle dependencies

```
compile ‘org.bytedeco:javacv:+’
compile group: ‘org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets’, name: ‘opencv’, version:   ‘2.4.10–0.10', classifier: ‘android-arm’ 
compile group: ‘org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets’, name: ‘ffmpeg’, version:   ‘2.5.1–0.10', classifier: ‘android-arm’
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice.

Comment: without these compile dependencies I had NoClassDefFoundError  in Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class); Here is a good help about the error http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Comment: Also there is a similar topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890116/javacv-android-studio-gradle-possible/30345905#30345905